# Case conversion with python regular expression back reference within pandas

Tags: python, pandas, case

I would like to do following:

```
data={'Name':['Mcdonald']}
df=pandas.DataFrame(data)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace('Mc([a-z])', "Mc"+r'\1'.upper(), regex=True)
```

Expected result: McDonald

Given result: Mcdonald

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.str.replace`:

```py
df["Name"] = df["Name"].str.replace(
    r"(?<=Mc)([a-z]+)", lambda g: g.group(1).title(), regex=True
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       Name
0  McDonald
1  McArthur
```

---

`df` used:

```
       Name
0  Mcdonald
1  Mcarthur
```